# jQuery issues page does not open

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jQuery(case-sensitive).
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jQuery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jQuery(case-sensitive).

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
every time i trying to get in to the page it doing the same problem

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="change username.aspx.cs" Inherits="settings_change_username" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   <title>Account Set|swapy</title>
    <link href="../css/MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <link rel="shortcut icon" type="icon/x-icon" href="../Logo/logof.png" />
</head>
<body style="background-image:url('../images/settings img/settings back.jpg');background-size:cover;color:goldenrod;font-size:larger">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <center><h1>Account Settings</h1></center>
    <div style="background-color:#100f0f">
     <center>
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
          <asp:TableRow>
              <asp:TableCell><nav class="menu">
        <ul class="clearfix">
            <li>
                <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">Profile Settings</a>

                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="change username.aspx">Change User name</a></li>
                    <li><a href="change pass.aspx">Change password</a></li>
                    <li><a href="change email.aspx">Change Email</a></li>
                     <li><a href="change phone number.aspx">Change phone number</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav></asp:TableCell>
              <asp:TableCell><span class="set-manu"><a href="Dealete account.aspx">Delete Acount</a></span></asp:TableCell>
              <asp:TableCell><span class="set-manu"><a href="View Pro.aspx">View my profile Acount</a></span></asp:TableCell>
          </asp:TableRow>
      </asp:Table>
     </center>
    </div>
        <div id="Connected" runat="server" style="position:relative;margin-left:3%">
                <h2 style="color:red">Welcome <b><span id="Usernamec" runat="server" style="color:goldenrod"></span></b></h2><br />
            </div>
        <center><div id="change" style="position:relative" runat="server">
            <center>
            <br /><br /><asp:TextBox CssClass="txt" ID="txtuser" runat="server" placeholder="Enter New Username"></asp:TextBox>
            <span  style="color:red"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="Rfvuser" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/T/A/y/b/C/x-mark-hi.png' width='30px' height='30px'/>password is Required" ControlToValidate="txtuser"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></span>
             <asp:TextBox CssClass="txt" ID="re" runat="server" placeholder="Repeat New Username"></asp:TextBox>
            <span  style="color:red"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RfvReuser" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/T/A/y/b/C/x-mark-hi.png' width='30px' height='30px'/>Please Repeat password" ControlToValidate="re"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br /><asp:CompareValidator ID="Cmuser" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/T/A/y/b/C/x-mark-hi.png' width='30px' height='30px'/>The passwords dont mach" ControlToCompare="txtuser" ControlToValidate="re"></asp:CompareValidator>
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="CVPass" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/T/A/y/b/C/x-mark-hi.png' width='30px' height='30px'/>The Password is taken" EnableClientScript="False" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator>
            </span>
            <asp:Button ID="changeBtn" OnClick="changeBtn_Click" CssClass="login" runat="server" Text="Change"></asp:Button>
        </div>

            <div id="sure" visible="false" style="position:relative" runat="server">
                                <span style="color:red"><h2 >Are You Sure?</h2> that you want to change your username to: <span id="pa" runat="server"></span></span><br /><br />
                <asp:TextBox CssClass="txt" ID="Pvpass" runat="server" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password"></asp:TextBox></center>
              <span  style="color:red"><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvpvpass" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/T/A/y/b/C/x-mark-hi.png' width='30px' height='30px'/>Please Enter your previous password password" ControlToValidate="Pvpass"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator><asp:CustomValidator ID="CVcheck" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/T/A/y/b/C/x-mark-hi.png' width='30px' height='30px'/>The Password is not your previous one" EnableClientScript="False" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator></span>
               <br /><br /><br /> <asp:Button CssClass="login" ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Change" OnClick="ins_Click" /><asp:Button CssClass="cencel" OnClick="button3_Click" ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
           </div>
        </center>
           <a class="button" href="index.aspx">Home page</a> <a class="button" href="Account settings.aspx">Account Settings</a>
    </form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Did you Google it? You didn't Google it, did you? Do you know how I know that? I copied and pasted the message into Google and found the above duplicate.

Comment: i saw it and googled it

Comment: but i did not understand where i should put that code

Comment: You should have included that in your question here, then. Either way, as the answer says, you need to put it in your web.config.